# Pass Data to Form Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have many items on a page and a person can review each one. When they click "review" a lightbox will open with a form to fill out. To know what is being reviewed I am passing the item name into a form field. However I cannot get the data to pass.

How do I pass the item name into the form?

Here is the code attempted:

***HTML***

```
<div class="element indica" data-category="indica">
  <p class="type">I</p>
  <h2 class="name">Name</h2> <!-- Information I want to pass -->
  <p class="strain-info">Information Here</p>
  <p class="review"><a class="fancy_button review-form-lb" href="#review-form-lightbox"><span style="background-color: #000;">Review Strain</span></a></p>
</div>
```

***FORM CODE***

```
<!-- I omitted form code not relevant to question. -->
<input name="CAT_Custom_365569" type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_365569" value=" " maxlength="4000" readonly="readonly" />
```

***JS***

```
$('.fancy_button').click(function(){
   var strain = $(this).prev('h2').text();
   $('#CAT_Custom_365569').val(strain);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prev` selects the **immediate** previous sibling, so it won't work in your case. Passing a selector means "grab the previous sibling *only if* it matches". Try this:

```
var strain = $(this).closest('div').find('h2').text();
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple I was overlooking. Thanks for the help. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

@elclanrs is right prev selects the immediate previous sibling, and when you give it a selector it validates that the previous meets the selector criteria.

Here is another way to achieve your desired result.

```
$('.fancy_button').click(function(){   
    var strain = $(this).parent().siblings('h2').text();   
    $('#CAT_Custom_365569').val(strain);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

When outputting the HTML, add a new attribute called "data-name" to the a element:

```
<a data-name="the name" class="fancy_button review-form-lb" href="#review-form-lightbox"><span style="background-color: #000;">Review Strain</span></a>
```

Then in your click handler, do this:

```
$('.fancy_button').click(function(){
   var strain = encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('data-name'));
   $('#CAT_Custom_365569').val(strain);
});
```

The benefit here is that you don't have to rely on some markup outside of the link that could possibly change in the future. I also encoded the name value just in case there are characters in there that could mess things up... that may or may not apply.

Comment: Depending on the possible values for names, you might want to encode the name in the data-name attribute, and then you don't have to encodeURIComponent in the js click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Class selectors are prefixed with a dot.

```
$(".element indica").find('.name').val();
```